# How i enable advanced search and what are the steps to enable

Tags: 2013, search, advanced-search

i have a share point 2013  publishing site deployed to internet and search working fine,
and i need to enable advanced search for this site for that users also can search by some fields like news,employeeno etc , how i enable advanced search and what are the steps to enable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not seeing advance search webpart in webpart gallery. Below is what you can do.

Go to the Advanced Search page in the search center site. Edit the page and Export the Advanced Search Web Part. After saving the exported web part file to your computer, go to the Web Part Gallery in the top level Site settings. Click "Files" in the ribbon tabs and upload the file you just downloaded.

At that point, the Advanced Search Web Part should show up under the "Miscellaneous" group when inserting a web part a Team Site page. If you edit the properties of the Advanced Search Web Part file in the Web Part Gallery to have a group of "Search" then it will show up under the Search group.

[Ref link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/99e6d5f2-76da-4fdd-8464-24159f12cee1/advanced-search-box-web-part-is-missing)